# Order the Languages by Display Name in the Content Editor

Tags: content-editor, multilingual

I would like to list out the languages by display name in the language selection. 
 Right now they default to the item name.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to not override this kind of stuff. Editors can leave with default order.

Comment: Hi My requirement is like that sorry :)

Comment: @Jai check out this article I think this is what you are looking for (http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2015/08/change-sort-order-of-languages-in.html)

Comment: @jay, I believe Tony has provided the right answer! or are you still looking for another solution?

Comment: Do not change those stuffs, overriding may result in performance and also is it high important to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can use setting `ContentEditor.SortLanguages` to manually sort them in content tree.

```
<!--
  CONTENT EDITOR SORT LANGUAGES
          Indicates whether the Content Editor show languages in the language selection dropdown
          in the same order as /sitecore/system/Languages child items.
          Default value: false

-->
<setting name="ContentEditor.SortLanguages" value="true" />
```